# The Penpal of Darkness

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I used to play tennis, 
> but not anymore
>   A pen pal of darkness, 
> though you hate our speech
>   A friend of a friend 
> of a bar and a horse
>   In children's games,
>  I help with the layout for each
>   I am down to Earth
>   I wouldn't be a great dam,
>   But for what it's worth
>   **Can you guess what I am?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> **Chalk**

I used to play tennis, 
but not anymore

> Chalk used to be used to mark Tennis Courts, now I believe paint is far more common.

A pen pal of darkness, 
though you hate our speech

> Used to write on blackboards, sometimes squeaking most unpleasantly

A friend of a friend 
of a bar and a horse

> Used on hands in Gymnastics, including several events involving Bars, and the Pommel Horse

In children's games,
I help with the layout for each

> Chalk used to mark lines for a bunch of kid's games, including Hopscotch and FourSquare

I am down to Earth
I wouldn't be a great dam,

> Mineral from rock or soil, but dissolves in water.